# Component not showing in admin top Menu only for `Editor` security group

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu-item, acl, user-groups

I have created component using Joomla`s official guide. It works well except one thing: user with security group "Editor" can access and modify the component but cannot see it in admin top main menu. 
In fact super user can see all the components in menu but "Editor" can not. 
I already checked global configuration and Menu manager.

My component is not present in menu manager items. Can this be a cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the User Group **Editor** does not have access to the back-end of the site, check with more detail the full description for each group here:

- [User Group Access levels explained in simple terms](https://docs.joomla.org/User_Group_Access_levels_explained_in_simple_terms)

Joomla! is very flexible, so you can adjust the permissions to be able to give access to the user group in this section of your site, follow this simple step:

- Go to **System** > **Global Configuration** > **Permissions** Tab

  From here select the User Group Editor, inside you can see options like **Access Administration Interface**